# Передача данных через объект $event в функцию

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Есть поле `input`, в котором при каждом нажатии клавиши на клавиатуре хочу передавать данные через `$event` в функцию:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="search($event)" />
```

В .ts-файле, в методе, хочу работать с этим объектом:

```
search(str: any) { console.log("str = " + str) }
```

Здесь хотел через `str` брать текст из input-элемента, но не получается - у меня нет свойств для `str`, когда ставлю точку после `str`. В консоль выводится

```
str = [object KeyboardEvent].
```

Как мне работать с этим объектом - мне всего-то нужно брать значение из `input` при каждом нажатии какой-либо клавиши? Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: пожалуйста, примите правку вашего вопроса. В правке улучшено форматирование.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular